# Timezone Dropdown List in User Account

Tags: datetime

Doe anyone know how to change the timezone dropdown list in the user account/registration? 
So which file is the menu/settings located in? (Assuming I am using Garland theme if that matters, and the variables will still be stored as a string, ie America/Chicago). Alternatively, how to change the user registration/account settings page so I can key in my own dropdown form.

Thanks!

[The reason is that it is quite difficult to find some locations in the US on it (It would make sense to make the American cities easier to find in their own section rather than in a collective North & South & Central America). So I want to be able to set in some choices manually or at least make it more intuitive (such as sorting by GMT +/-, I understand the issues with timezone, unix time, etc ...meaning they depend on the political area and jurisdiction, along with DST in some states and not so in others, ie Indiana, Arizona etc...)]

I was thinking of changing the format to this:

'America/Denver' => '(GMT-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)',
'America/Chihuahua' => '(GMT-07:00) Mexico/Chihuahua',
'America/Phoenix' => '(GMT-07:00) USA/Arizona',
'America/Regina' => '(GMT-06:00) Canada/Saskatchewan',
'America/Tegucigalpa' => '(GMT-06:00) Central America',
'America/Chicago' => '(GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)',

Comment: What version of drupal are you using (i'm assuming 7)?

Answer (score 2):

User register forms are built by the User module, but the timezone widget is added by the Locale module through [locale_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--locale--locale.module/function/locale_form_alter/7%29) (an implementation of `hook_form_alter()`).

The Drupal community suggests leaving the core files alone (see [Do not hack core](http://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core)). If you want to change the form, just write your own implementation of `hook_form_alter()`, and add/edit the available values using the form API and the ["select" form field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#select).

There is a nice tutorial at [Brenda Boggs blog](http://www.alligatorsneeze.com/drupal-alters-and-overrides-hookformalter).

Answer (score 0):

You can not configure those options in menu management interface.
System module alter the user editing form: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.module/function/system_form_user_profile_form_alter/7 > then add timezone widget, options returned by this function system_time_zones().